# Estoy teniendo problemas para guardar los datos en localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

La consola retorna `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')at app.js:148:14` verifique la forma en la que estoy escuchando el evento, tambien que el id este en el documento y por ultimo lo intente con querySelector tambien, de la siguiente manera, pero no funciono.

```
const guardarDatos = document.querySelector("#guardar");
```

Dejo el fragmento de código en JavaScript

```
const guardarDatosJSON = ()=>{
    const datosForm = {descripcion:"", tipo:"", valor:0}
        datosForm.descripcion = descripcion.value;
        datosForm.tipo = tipo.value;
        datosForm.valor = valor.value;
        localStorage.setItem("datosForm", JSON.stringify(datosForm))
}
const guardarDatos = document.getElementById('guardar')


guardarDatos.addEventListener("click", guardarDatosJSON)
```

HTML

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div class="agregar">
        <div class="agregar__contenedor">
            <select class="agregar__tipo" id="tipo">
                <option value="ingreso" selected>+</option>
                <option value="egreso" selected>-</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" class="agregar__descripcion" placeholder="Agregar Descripción" id="descripcion">
            <input type="number" class="agregar__valor" placeholder="Valor" id="valor" step="any">
            <button class="agregar__btn" onclick="agregarDato()" >
                <ion-icon name="checkmark-circle-outline" id="guardar"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Donde tienes la etiqueta script que referencia tu código javascript? ¿Al inicio de la página? ¿Tienes al menos tu código dentro de `window.onload = function() {.. tu código}`?

Comment: Como primera medida tienes un form, aunque no tengas un input submit cualquier boton hara el submit asi que tienes que capturar el evento y tomar el control con javascript (preventdefault). Todo eso ta lo tienes hecho?

Comment: Hola! gracias por responder, asi es, lo tengo al inicio de la pagina, entre las etiquetas <head>. No, mi código no esta entre dentro de window.onload = function() , crees que eso es lo que hace que no funcione?

Comment: Pasa la etiqueta `<script>` al final de la página, para que se ejecute después de haber cargado el DOM.